# Generate GPG key without saving to keychain

Tags: gnupg, pipe, pgp, stdout

I am trying to generate a GPG key with `gnupg`. However, instead of exporting the secret key to a file, I am trying to pipe it to another program (`keybase pgp import`) that will process it.

Right now, I am using `gpg --full-gen-key --expert -o -`.

However, the piped output is not what I was looking for:

```
pub   ed25519 2021-08-27 [SC]
      0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567
uid                      Allice Bobeve
sub   cv25519 2021-08-27 [E]
```

The secret key is exported to my keychain instead of to `stdout` as I intended.

**What is the correct `gnupg` command to generate a secret key and export it directly into `stdout`, without storing it in my local keychain?**
In your answer, please explain all flags and options. I would still like to use the interactive prompts for selecting a key type and size (or curve type), creating a UID, etc.

*Migrated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68958557*

Comment: Create it in a temporary keyring by setting GNUPGHOME to a temporary directory, then delete it.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I don't want to save the key to my disk at all—I just want to pipe the output directly to another command. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid writing to a file, though I don't know internals well enough to answer. However, nearly all Unix systems support RAM filesystems that don't write anything to disk, and you can certainly use one of those. (For that matter, in traditional Unix pipe buffers _can_ be written to disk.) For Windows I believe this can be done with third-party products, but I haven't done so.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 How would I go about using a RAM filesystem for this?

Comment: On my handiest test systems, CentOS (7) and Ubuntu (18.04), /dev/shm is tmpfs and allows me to create (and later delete) an arbitrary subdirectory. Other systems may be different, and some may require some setup or knowledge.